# Issue after device rotation with series of CheckBoxes

Tags: android, checkbox, rotation, oncreate

I have a LinearLayout in which I inflate several CheckBoxes from an xml file. They work as expected; however when the screen rotates (and thus the Activity is destroyed/recreated) a weird bug is happening. Say there are 6 checkboxes, and they have text 'one', 'two' etc through 'six'. After rotation, all six of them will read 'six'. This persists no matter what I attempt, until I run a custom function which either adds or deletes one of the checkboxes, at which point the remaining ones show their proper text again, and in the proper order.

Here's the XML for the checkbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/groupcreate_entry"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
      //The above two lines allow the checkbox to be to the right of the text.
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

And the code in question:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    private ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.groupcreate);

    LinearLayout groupCreate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.groupCreate);
    setupGroupViews();
}

private void setupGroupViews() {
    groupCreate.removeAllViews();
    CheckBox[] textBox = new CheckBox[groupNames.size()];
        //I originally reused the same CheckBox each time, but switched to an
        //array to try debugging this issue; no luck

    for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.size(); i++) {
        textBox[i] = (CheckBox) (getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.groupcreate_entry, groupCreate, false));
        textBox[i].setText(groupNames.get(i));
        registerForContextMenu(textBox[i]);
        groupCreate.addView(textBox[i]);
    }
}
```

In the function where I add or delete a checkbox, I don't do much more than add/remove it from the ArrayList groupNames and rerun setupGroupViews.

I've tried running groupCreate.invalidate() in onCreate() to no effect. I'm *guessing* it has something to do with the activity being redrawn, but I've tried a bunch of things and can't figure out what it is. Is it because I'm inflating each CheckBox using the same layout file? Is that why it redraws them all with the same text of the last created CheckBox?

Getting toward my wit's end; any and all input appreciated. Happy to clarify if anything needs it.

Edit: Another function I created allows you to edit the text of the checkbox through a right-click context menu which brings up a dialog. If you go to edit the text of, say, the first checkbox, which *should* have text of 'one' in this example but instead reads 'six', the dialog pulls the checkbox's text via getText().toString() and it does indeed show the incorrect text of 'six'. However, no matter what modifications you make to the text in the dialog, once you hit Ok and submit the change, all the checkboxes go back to their correct text, and it will read 'one' again.

I'm wondering if it's in some way holding on to references to deleted CheckBox views, but if so I don't know why as I call groupCreate.removeAllViews() before proceeding.

Comment: super.onCreate() must be the first thing you call in onCreate(). Not sure that will fix your issue yet, but that's something you need to change for sure.

Comment: That's there, I added the ArrayList declaration first for clarity, as otherwise it's done before onCreate and I was simplifying what I included. Good point though =)

Comment: Can we see your implementation of onSaveInstanceState()?

Comment: At the moment I'm not overriding that method. Can you suggest what I should include with it besides passing the bundle to super? As far as I'm aware, everything that I'd need saved is already saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that all your `CheckBox` instances are using the same id `groupcreate_entry`.

Android restores View data based on object id, so when it was saving, it was pulling the item id and saving its respective value. When restoring, it was looking at each element, and giving it the value saved for that id (which was "six", the last value saved for `groupcreate_entry`).

**Solution**: try giving the objects their own unique ids, and then it should fix it. The other option, of course, is to simply override the default behaviour.

Comment: Hell yes! This did the trick. I wasn't setting any id explicitly, I was inflating them all from the same layout file. I just tested this and it was setting their id to some ten-digit integer, and it was the same for all of them. Explicitly setting their id with textBox[i].setId(i) (thus setting their id to the current counter value) works like a charm.